# Flutter Navigator pop to specific screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, navigator

I have a Flutter app with three screens

```
Home Screen 
Items List Screen 
Item Screen
```

The normal navigation is

```
Home Screen -> Item List Screen -> Items Screen 
Items Screen <- Items List Screen <- Home Screen
```

I want to implement a different navigation when I get a Notification. the new navigation should be

```
Home Screen -> Item Screen
Item Screen <- Item List Screen <- Home Screen
```

How can I implement this using Navigator push and pop?

Comment: To properly navigate through screens in MaterialApp, I recommended utilizing the navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil method and create a route.

Comment: I'm currently using this but the problem is that push animates forward transition so in the second implementation when a notification comes I forward to the Item Screen but when I try to to press the back button (in order to go to Items List) it animates forward transition

Comment: Make use of the 'pop' and 'push' methods, and also utilize the Navigator accordingly.

Comment: In the second navigation the point I'm missing is how I will add the "Item List Screen" in navigation stack when I go from Home Screen to Item Screen  in order to pop from Item Screen to Item List Screen